# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} : how to stop, if REQUEST_URI contains ?p=about or ?p=contact

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm trying to create a rewrite condition in .htaccess file to check if url contains a parameter p that is set and parameter p=about or p=contact.
In case, if ?p=about or ?p=contact, the RewriteRule that is below should NOT be berformed.
Could anybody help me with RewriteCond?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?p=about_us|?p=contact)
```

does NOT work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RewriteCond below will match if the query string does not have a `p` param with a value of `about us` or `contact` i.e the following rule will not execute if it has a p= `about us` or `contact`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)p=(about_us|contact)(&|$) [NC]
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted... its a nice answer. I will upvote it now.
However you may know OP wanted to skip the rules if above condition is met so you pls put negation `!` like this: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)p=(about_us|contact)(&|$) [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! I missed the negation but its now in

Comment: I'm also not sure who downvoted. I've tested it, and it works. That's a solution for my question. Thank you very much!