# What does `&` signify in PCRE?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pcre

Tried searching in [PCRE Documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt). Couldn't find anything.

What does `&` signify in PCRE?

Saw a usage of it in an expression like this:

`(^|&)p=(about_us|contact)(&|$) [NC]`

in this question: [RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} : how to stop, if REQUEST_URI contains ?p=about or ?p=contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926101/rewritecond-request-uri-how-to-stop-if-request-uri-contains-p-about-or-p/8926479#8926479)

I do know the meanings of `^`, `$` & `|`. as well as grouping.

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning. Could you paste the full expression?

Comment: `&` is just a regular character that will be matched.

Comment: @BoltClock have posted the full expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have any special meaning.

I imagine that the expression is simply trying to match either the start or end of the query string, or otherwise a literal `&` character on either end of the query string. Remember that `&` is typically used to separate query string parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```
^ =the start of the phrase
$ = the end of the word
| = or operator (ab|bc) will accept both ab and bc
& doesnt have special meaning
```

grouping is used in order to use the values later (instead of just checking if the string matches)
use can use the matches that you catched in a parenthesis.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1
```

this will take the file that is being accesses and pass it as parameter r to the index.php file

the phrase you pasted is looking for 4 different situations.
1. p=... [as the whole qs]
2. the qs starts with p=...& but contains other parameters as well
3. &p=... - p is the last parameter
4. &p=...& - p is in the middle of the qs